# How to listen for current thread changes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know in every moment of program execution what thread is executed now (not all threads in JVM but only threads that belong to my program).

How can I get it?

Comment: perhaps with a profiler.

Answer (score 1):

YourKit can show you which threads were running, blocked, waiting etc at any given moment and give you a snapshot of the stack at intervals.

You can create a process to poll all the threads yourself with  `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` which gives you the stack trace of every thread.  Using a GUI tool is much, much easier.

Comment: `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` lists all live threads including even sleeping one. Is it possible to get only those threads that are executed just at the moment? Or to listen for events like `current thread changes`?

Comment: You can have a list of threads of interest and call getStackTrace on each one.  What sort of thread changes are you interested in?

Comment: I want to listen for situations when processor changes current executed thread from one thread of my program to another thread of my program. Between these 2 executions other threads that don't belong to my program may be executed.

Comment: This would require OS support.  Amost nobody wants such information,  and OS developers don't want to supply it.

Comment: Even if you could do that, you would have the problem that the monitoring thread might not be running when this happens.  You should re-think why you believe you want this information because it is highly likely there is a better/simpler way to solve your problem.